# Alma Linux で TigerVNC をsystemd 経由のサービスとして起動したい

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, vnc

#### 経緯

Alma Linuxを動かしてサーバを構築している途中です。
Alma LinuxにVNCサーバを入れることで、リモートからGUI環境で作業したいと思っています。

##### 知りたいこと

VNCサーバーを入れる手順で手こずっており、
もし適切な手順をご存知のかたおられましたらご教示お願いします。

#### 現状

VNCサーバーをインストールして、一時的に起動するまではいくのですが、すぐにinactive(dead)になってしまいます。

参考資料を基にvncserverをインストール・設定

起動手順

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver@:2
sudo systemctl status vncserver@:2
```

起動時の実行結果

```
● vncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-10-14 18:48:27 JST; 1s ago
  Process: 8388 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/vncsession-restore :2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8408 (vncsession)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 409535)
   Memory: 1.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@:2.service
           ? 8408 /usr/sbin/vncsession nemoto :2

10月 14 18:48:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
10月 14 18:48:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
```

`sudo systemctl status vncserver@:2` を再び入力すると下記の画面になってしまいます。

```
● vncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-10-14 18:45:55 JST; 1min 55s ago
  Process: 8281 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/vncsession-start :2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8261 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/vncsession-restore :2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8281 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

10月 14 18:45:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
10月 14 18:45:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
10月 14 18:45:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:2.service: Succeeded.
```

`/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service` の設定ファイルで不備等があるのかと考えていますが、どのように変更したらいいか分かりませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

**設定ファイル**

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=+/usr/libexec/vncsession-restore %i
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/vncsession-start %i
PIDFile=/run/vncsession-%i.pid
SELinuxContext=system_u:system_r:vnc_session_t:s0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**VNC Server 起動時のログ**

```
Using desktop session gnome

New 'localhost.localdomain:2 (nemoto)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:2

Starting desktop session gnome


Xvnc TigerVNC 1.12.0 - built Apr 18 2022 14:13:34
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12011000, The X.Org Foundation


Fri Oct 14 21:30:19 2022
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
xinit: connection to X server lost
^M
waiting for X server to shut down
Fri Oct 14 21:30:24 2022
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
```

**実行環境:**
tigervnc server 1.12.0
AlmaLinux 8.4 (Electric Cheetah)

**参考資料**
[CentOS 7 で GNOME デスクトップ用の VNC リモート アクセスをインストールおよび設定する方法](https://arquidiamantina.org/ja/centos-7-%E3%81%A7-gnome-%E3%83%87%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE-vnc-%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4/)
[alma linuxにTigerVNCを入れて動かした](https://note.com/pien2021/n/nbdf9794e7d5e)

Answer (score 1):

`Type=simple` ではなく、`Type=forking` でいいはず。
その他、/etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users でディスプレイ番号(:2)とユーザーの紐付けが必要です。
VNC Server 起動時のログは、ユーザーの .vnc/ホスト名:2.log に出力されますので、そちらも確認ください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Type=forkingに変更してみましたが、状況変わらず。ユーザーとディスプレイ番号（:2）の紐づけは実施してありました。logは質問画面に追記しましたので、確認頂けると幸いです。

Comment: VNC 実行ユーザーにスイッチ(su - nemoto)して、"vncserver :2" で起動できますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。VNC 実行ユーザーにスイッチ(su - nemoto)して、"vncserver :2" では起動できなかったです。”vncserver@2:service.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1” のエラーが出ます。

Comment: VNC 実行ユーザーで "vncserver :2" で起動できないときのエラーは？

Comment: コメント遅くなりすいません。vncserver :2を入力すると下記の内容が表示されます。

WARNING: vncserver has been replaced by a systemd unit and is now considered dep                                                                             recated and removed in upstream.
Please read /usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md for more information.

New 'localhost.localdomain:2 (nemoto)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:2

Starting applications specified in /home/nemoto/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/nemoto/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:2.log

Comment: 更に起動できない時のエラーは"systemctl status vncserver@2:service"で確認すると、下記が表示されます。
● vncserver@2:service.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-14 23:49:29 JST; 17h ago
  Process: 13057 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/vncsession-restore 2:service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: 一旦、systemctl は置いておきましょう。
"vncserver :2" でエラーなく起動しているように見えます。
"ss -tln | grep :5902" で LISTEN していませんか？

Comment: 私の理解が悪くすいません。”ss -tln | grep :5902”を入力して、LISTENしているか確認するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？